# Getting user's AD groups as lookup

Tags: lookup-column, active-directory, groups

I'm trying to make a simple reservation site, containing two lists: resources and reservations. Users are making reservations by creating a new item on Reservations list, specifying which resource they need, time when they will be using it and for what project will it be used for.

The thing is that we don't want to move all projects to sharepoint, as they already exist as groups in AD. So the big question is: Can I create a lookup field which will fill with AD groups? Ideally, it should show only groups in which the user making the reservation is a member.

Comment: Can you specify if you are willing/able to do this programmatically? As far as I know, there isn't any elegant solutions to accomplish this otherwise.

Comment: If you mean with Visual Studio, I have never done that, but have a little experience in .NET. If you mean with JavaScript, I have never done that either, but I'm willing to try ;)